# How much algebra one needs to study algebraic topology and homotopy theory?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I wonder how much algebra(group theory, abstract algebra, linear algebra, ring theory, field theory) is assumed as a prerequisite in most of the modern algebraic topology text.
For example, these

J.Strom "Modern Classical Homotopy Theory"

Tammo tom Dieck "Algebraic Topology"

P.May "A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology.

Comment: A solid course worth of material should do it, covering for example Lang's *Algebra* — all of Part I, some (~half?) of Parts II and III, the chapter on homology theory in part IV (which you could probably read in parallel to the texts you mention). Parts II and III  are well worth knowing but aren't prerequisite.

Comment: I hope you haven't been thinking about prerequisites since your post a few months ago. If something sounds interesting, try to read it. You'll learn soon enough whether or not you should hit the algebra harder.

Comment: Keep in mind that something like May's book is more of a reference for those that know the subject, rather than comprehensive book for beginners (from my personal experience)

Comment: IMO for the most part, until you get pretty deep into the subject, the algebra required in homotopy theory is pretty light, just basic definitions and more or less obvious results (groups, rings, modules). There is a bit of homological algebra, but that's not deep either, just a bit of work once you have the basic definitions. The further you go the fancier the algebra gets.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer and let me know if there is I could help you any further. Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate if you would like to accept my answer. Also let me know if you have any further questions and I will be very happy to answer them.

Answer (score 4):

The question highly depends on how deep you would like to go into algebraic topology.

If you are interested in learning algebraic topology as a general knowledge i.e. in the level of  *Hatcher's* beafutiful book ***Algebraic Topology***, then you probably need to know group, ring, and field theory, especially the structure of graded rings, and some basics of homological algebra such as $Ext$, and $Tor$. Note that there is actually no need to worry about homological algebra since all the required knowledge is introduced in that book when needed. Therefore, it is fair to say a good knowledge of abstract algebra should suffices to take a first course in algebraic topology.

If you would like to go further, such as studying stable homotopy theory, you probably want to have a good knowledge of category theory without which you could not even define the stable homotopy category which is central in algebraic topology. You also want to know more about homological algebra which enables you to study important topics like spectral sequences. You also need to learn about the theory of formal group laws to understand Quillen's celebrated theorem  which establishes the relation between the universal complex oriented cohomology theory and the Lazard ring.

It is really hard to answer your question in the full completeness. What I mentioned in the above should only serve as a "*necessary condition*". Hope this answer helps.